# zsh prompt replace named directory with it's alias

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, prompt

As I understand, if you create an alias for a directory in your .zshrc file, that directory is now considered a "named directory". I could be mistaken there, so let me know.

Based on the documentation [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state), it sounds like if you use "%~" in your zsh prompt and the current working directory is a named directory, then the prompt should show the alias for the directory, rather than the full path (i.e. `~{alias}`). This does not seem to be working for me currently and I'm having a hard time finding examples or posts regarding this.

In my .zshrc file I have an alias like `repo = "~/src/apps/repo"`. My hope is that when I am in that directory, the zsh prompt would show `~repo`, but it always shows the full thing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh, you can add a named directory with `hash -d repo=~/src/apps/repo` (not an alias). Also, `~` isn't expanded inside quotes, so you should remove them or use `$HOME` instead.

- `hash` usage: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-hash-1
- Static named directories: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories

Comment: Ah thank you! That works like a charm. I had gotten bad direction elsewhere that an alias would work the same.